# Disable input in Bootstrap 4 after error with calling Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a form in Bootstrap 4 which, through XMLHttpRequest, verifies that a Serial Number is not already inserted.
If it already is, I open a div where I notify the user that the Serial Number is already present.
How can I disable the rest of the form or the Submit button when opening the div?
On the content of the div that opens there is a button that resets the form, so one method is worth the other.
It is enough for me that the rest of the form cannot be sent.
Thanks in advance.

**Input Form**

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id_cliente">Num. Tessera:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control no-slide" id="id_cliente" placeholder="Inserisci Numero Tessera" name="id_cliente" required onchange="chkTessera(this.value)">
          <div class="valid-feedback">Valido.</div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Per favore compila questo campo.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="txtTessera"></div>
```

**chk_Tessera Function**

```
function chkTessera(str) {
if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtTessera").innerHTML="";
    return;
}

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 
          document.getElementById("txtTessera").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","chk_tessera.php?key="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();   }
```

**chk_tessera.php**

```
<?php

 $db = new SQLiteDB();

 $id_cliente = $_GET['key'];

 $sql = <<<EOF
   SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE id_cliente = $id_cliente;
 EOF;

 $result = $db->query($sql);

 $num_righe = 0;     
     while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
    ++$num_righe;
 }

 if($num_righe > 0){

 ?>

 <div class="mw-100 bg-warning">
     <div class="alert alert-danger" >
         <strong>ATTENZIONE!</strong> Il Numero di Tessera risulta già 
  assegnato.
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
  onclick="window.location.replace('ins_anagrafica_cliente.php')">OK</button>
  </div>

 </div>

<?php
}
```

?>

Comment: Add a "disabled" class to the button on failure. that;s all

Comment: Done, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post a link to JSBin so we can check

Answer (score 0):

Just add a attribute to that element

```
$.ajax({
 url: '',
 success: function(){
   $('#id_cliente').attr('disabled','disabled');
 },
 error: function(){}
});
```